# Installation of SharePoint 2010 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 to F: drive. Initially I was getting the following error:

```
"The INSTANCESHAREDWOWDIR command line value was not specified"
```

Then I copied the configuration file .ini from SQL location and changed the location to the F: drive and placed this config to F: location.

Then I tried installation of SQL Server 2008 from command prompt and used the following command:

```
setup.exe 
-/Action=Install 
-/INSTALLSHAREDDIR="F:\Microsoft Sql Server\\"
-/INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="F:\Microsoft Sql Server(x86)\\"
```

I was able to install successfully, but still when I Install SharePoint 2010 server, it creates all the database to C: drive by default.  I have the LDF and MDF files copied to F: drive manually.

What I want is for these databases to be created on drive F: when I install SharePoint. Anyone have any guidance or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the *Database default locations* paths in *Server Properties*:

[image: Database default locations]

Source: [Changing the default location of SQL Server Data and Log files](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Changing_default_location_of_Data_and_Log_files.html)